# Morphological erosion on digital images with Python - error

Tags: python, mathematical-morphology

I tried implementing morphological erosion on digital images with Python. I uploaded a binary image and defined a structural element - ones(3,3). But when I run the code, the following error occurs:

RuntimeError: sequence argument must have length equal to input rank

Please assit. Below are my codes:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage import data, io, color

bi_im1 = plt.imread("binary1.jpg")
plt.imshow(bi_im1)
print("Original binary image1")

def plot_comparison(original, filtered, filter_name):

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots( ncols=2, figsize=(512, 256), sharex=True,
                                   sharey=True)
    ax1.imshow(original, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    #ax1.set_title('original')
    ax1.axis('off')
    ax2.imshow(filtered, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    ax2.set_title(filter_name)
    ax2.axis('off')

from skimage.morphology import (erosion, dilation, opening, closing)
from skimage.morphology import disk
selem = np.array([[1,1,1],
                    [1,1,1],
                    [1,1,1]])
plt.imshow(selem, cmap='gray', vmax=1, vmin=0);
eroded1 = erosion(bi_im1, selem)
plot_comparison(bi_im1, eroded1, 'erosion')
```

My binary image 'binary1.jpg' is uploaded below:

[binaryimage1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmdG5.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please post  the output of `bi_im1.shape`? It should be a binary image (with dimensions `(m,n)`) for the erosion operation to work.

Comment: I got it as
(256,256,3).

Does that mean this image is still not binary?

Comment: Exactly. You would need to convert it to a binary image and then perform erosion.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you to solve your problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting what I mentioned as a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67758203/morphological-erosion-on-digital-images-with-python-error/67761022#comment119766595_67758203) - You are trying to perform the erosion operation on a RGB image. You need to convert the RGB image to a binary image and then perform erosion with the structuring element.